# How to access a Request parameter in Laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-blade

I'm trying to set/unset the HTML `checked` attr based on the presence of a query string, but Laravel is throwing a syntax error:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="priority" {{ Request::get("my_checkbox") ? checked : null }} >
```

Somehow this doesn't parse correctly and I get a syntax error on one of the closing brackets:

> syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: isn't this should be `{{ Request::get("my_checkbox") ? 'checked' : null }}` ?

Comment: @SalmanZafar I tried this also, same syntax error.

Comment: try this `@if(request()->get('my_checkbox')) checked @endif`

Comment: @f7n Is this the only line in your blade? I would rather send a variable to the blade than accessing `Request` in the blade file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do that :

```
<input Type="checkbox" ="my_checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="priority" {{ Request::get("my_checkbox") ? 'checked' : null }} >
```

Comment: What's the use of null though? Make it an empty string `''`.

Comment: Its the same empty string or null